# boost::serialization and cyclic reference deserialization

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, c++11

I have a tree-like structure that needs to be serialized. Typical structure, with each node having `parent` members and `children` vectors. `parent` is a raw pointer-to-class, and `children` are `vector`s of `shared_ptr`s. Now it seems that serialization works fine, but *de*-serialization leaves the `parent` members uninitialized (pointers to `0xcccccccc` or `0x00000000`).

The `parent` members are being loaded when the actual parent object has not yet finished deserializing, i.e. the child's `parent` member is loaded through the deserialization request of the parent's `children`. Since this is cyclic I was wondering whether I need to take special measures for it to work.

Thanks for the help.

**Update:** This is how my serializing function looks like:

```
template <typename Archive>
void serialize(Archive& archive, GameCore::GameObject& t, const unsigned int version)
{
    archive & boost::serialization::base_object<GameCore::Object>(t);
    archive & boost::serialization::base_object<GameCore::Updatable>(t);
    archive & t.parent;
    archive & t.transform;
    archive & t.components;
    archive & t.children;
}
```

**If I comment out `archive & t.children`, `parent` gets populated correctly.**

**Update 2:** Ok, I've managed to turn this into a minimal sample that exhibits the problem. The following should compile:

```
#include <boost\archive\binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost\archive\binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class A
{
public:
    A() {}
    A(const A& rhs) = delete;

    int someInt = 0;
    A* parent = nullptr;
    std::vector<A*> children;

    template <class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& archive, const unsigned int version)
    {
        archive & someInt;
        archive & parent;
        int count = children.size();
        archive & count;
        children.resize(count);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        {
            A* ptr = children[i];
            archive & ptr;
            children[i] = ptr;
        }
    }
};


int main()
{
    A* newA = new A();
    newA->someInt = 0;

    A* newPtr = new A();
    newPtr->someInt = 5;
    newPtr->parent = newA;

    newA->children.push_back(newPtr);

    //  Save.
    std::ofstream outputFile("test", std::fstream::out | std::fstream::binary);
    if (outputFile.is_open())
    {
        boost::archive::binary_oarchive outputArchive(outputFile);

        //  Serialize objects.
        outputArchive << newA;
        outputFile.close();
    }

    delete newA;
    delete newPtr;

    A* loadedPtr = nullptr;

    //  Load.
    std::ifstream inputFile("test", std::fstream::binary | std::fstream::in);
    if (inputFile && inputFile.good() && inputFile.is_open())
    {
        boost::archive::binary_iarchive inputArchive(inputFile);

        //  Load objects.
        inputArchive >> loadedPtr;
        inputFile.close();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Step through the code. The child's `parent` stays null, always.

Comment: If anyone, *anyone* can replicate this problem, please let me know, cause it's driving me crazy!

Comment: FWIW: the program in update 2 (plus some asserts for validation) [works correctly at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/69a02441a7048015) so the problem is at your end.

Comment: Then what the hell am I doing wrong? I've tested this on two machines, two different Boost builds... Maybe I'm building wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, apparently I fell prey to another unlucky bug. Boost 1.55 doesn't yet have a working serialization library for VS2013, according to the [latest Boost release page](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_55_0.html). 
Talk about wasted time...

> Known Bugs with Visual Studio 2013/Visual C++ 12
>
> Visual Studio 2013
>   was released quite late in the release process, so there exist several
>   unresolved issues. These include:
>
> Serialization can't compile because of a missing include.

Comment: I don't see where you got that information. Can you quote/refer to the specific document location that tells you there isn't a serialization library for VS2013? (I can see that VC12 isn't listed under _(additional) test compilers_ yet, but that's a different matter)

Comment: Updated my answer with the quote, from the top of the page I linked.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in past, and I did not find solid solution from out-of-the-box.. but the following small hack works fine - you could specify serialization and de-serialization functions separately (not using default template and &-operator):

```
//! Serialization
void A::serialize(xml_oarchive& ar, const unsigned int version)
{
   ar << value;
}
//! De-serialization
void A::serialize(xml_iarchive& ar, const unsigned int version)
{
   ar >> value;
}
```

And after that you could specify restoring of a pointer to parent object in deserialization method, like the following:

```
//! Serialization
void A::serialize(xml_oarchive& ar, const unsigned int version)
{
   ar << children;
}
//! De-serialization
void A::serialize(xml_iarchive& ar, const unsigned int version)
{
   ar >> children;
   for(var child: children)
       child->parent = this;
}
```

Comment: Which version of boost were you using? I tried it at work with  pre-built 1.54 for x64 and the `parent` pointer was populated correctly. Btw, I am using your workaround in fact, but I also met the bug in places where a pointer is first deserialized fine, and then deserialized in a completely different place (without an easy workaround like this), with this second ending up null or uninitialized.

Comment: I think it was boost 1.33, but I am not sure. btw I've tested your code with 1.54 and 1.55 on gcc (mingw64), it works correctly. And I've also checked default reference counting in boost serialization, it works fine with tree structure, double-linked list, and cycled list - all pointers to parent elements are restored correctly.

Comment: Yeah it's VC++12 that's the problem.

Comment: You do not need to split serialization this way, it is not what is recommended by Boost. A preferred way is to have a unified function serialize with some sections under `if (typename Archive::is_loading())` or `if (typename Archive::is_saving())` if necessary. This way the chance of inconsistency between "save" and "load" is minimal. Alternatively, you can have separate functions with names "save" and "load" and then combine them using one of Boost.Serialize macros BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_FREE or BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_MEMBER.

Answer (score 1):

This has been resolved on the development branch.

See. https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/9601

Answer (score 0):

If you use Boost Serialization everything should work out-of-box. You class serialize can look like

```
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
void serialize (Archive&ar, unsigned int version)
{
     //declare possible derived types of nodes
     ar & parent;
     ar & children;
}
```

Archive will hash pointers so it will not create each element more than once.

One important detail: If your nodes can be of some derived type you need to teach archive what types to expect at // place,
see details in boost documentation on serializing derived types through pointers to base type.

If you are sure your tree structure is correct and self-contained (root has NULL as a parent, all other nodes are "children" of their respective "parent", etc.) than you can organize code a little more efficiently:

```
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
void serialize (Archive&ar, unsigned int version)
{
     //declare possible derived types of nodes (either here or at archive creation point)        
     ar & children;
     if (typename Archive::is_loading())
     {
          for (auto child : children)
             child->parent = this;
     }
}
```

(I assume you set "parent" to NULL in constructor).

I did not test this code with VS 2013.